# Dynamically assigned a Label Value and display a messages when values changes

Tags: c#

I have some code for C# that gets the second highest number from a table in the database:
The value or result-set is displayed in a text-box. This number changes every time a new record is inserted into the database.

I created another Label on the form and would like to display a message every time the value or text in the textbox is changed, which is dynamically.

In a nutshell, every time a record is inserted, this code runs and inserts the number in the textbox, I would like to display a message on another label every time the text-box value changes.

```
private void DataSets_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

    //Connection Strings
    string ConnString = @" Server=example;Database=example;Integrated Security=true";

    string sql = @"SELECT MAX(ClientID) FROM Clients WHERE ClientID <> (SELECT MAX(ClientID) FROM Clients)";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

    conn.Open();

    //CREATE DATA ADAPTER
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //FILL DATASET
    da.Fill(ds, "ClientID");

    txtDisplayData.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

    conn.Close();
    ds.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event and update your label from there e.g.

```
txtDisplayData.TextChanged += (sender, e) => {
    myLabel.Text = "Value changed to " + (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[TextChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event will be your friend

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but do I assigned the value for the database to the text-box? Like: In the Text_change event? I will read on this and get it. At least I know where to look. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is textbox property. open link and you will have full msdn definition and usages

Comment: Okay but I need this to happen dynamically, right now it is only working if I manually type n the textbox. I am assigning the Textbox value dynamically via page load event and on click the number changes but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TextBox.TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event for this process.

> Occurs when **content changes in the text box**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextChanged Event for label text change.